# Controller doen't exists

Tags: laravel

I am getting the following error:

> Target class [CustomersController] does not exists.

[image: Any suggestions for this exception? The controller is well defined and well called in the route, I can't find the problem]

Comment: What's your question about this? Why not create that missing class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use laravel 8 there are update in the RouteServiceProvider :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\NameOfController ;
Route::get('/index' , [NameOfController ::class,'index']);
```